# HTML email rendering strange on iPhone

Tags: html, ios, iphone, email

I'm developing an html email and am running into issues with rendering on iPhones. The email seems to show up perfectly fine on all email clients (gmail, outlook, hotmail, yahoo, etc...) & is showing up fine in other devices such as android, but iPhone seems to be the only problem.

The email is almost twice as long as it should be and there is nothing on the screen when you open it, you scroll down a long way and there is the email intact. Way at the bottom. Any thoughts on this?

any thoughts or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

I've tried running the code through litmus & emails on acid and everything shows up fine on those tests, however I have 2 different iPhones showing the same result. Both iPhone 6's.

Comment: How are you accessing the email? Safari or app or what?

Comment: I'm accessing it through the main mail app. However I found the issue this morning... one of those stupid mistakes....

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that the container table I had to center the rest of the email did not have any type of vertical alignment set into place. I just assumed it would go to the top, however in the iPhone it sent my email to the bottom of the page with a large top white space.

I added a vertical-align:top; & valign="top" to the table cell containing my email and it worked perfectly.

it just is strange how no other client or device was having this problem.